# How to find which process sent a HUP signal to my node.js process?

Tags: debian, signals

Every Monday at 9AM UTC something sends a `HUP` signal to my node.js process (and I think HUP is being sent to all processes, not just mine). How do I find which process sent the `HUP` signal to my program? My program has a HUP handler that makes it restart (to reload config), so every Monday at 9AM, my production stack restarts on its own (but keeps running, so all is good, it's just super annoying).

I have a feeling it's systemd doing it, I just don't know which part of systemd is doing it. Any ideas?

It's a Debian 11.7 installation.

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: Probably, you can see which process sent the HUP signal with `strace -p <PID>`.

Comment: if only on a specific time then it should be a crontab

Comment: The process is run via `screen`. It's a detached screen session. It runs like this: `while :; do node index.js; done` @vidarlo

Comment: @librhnylmz nice idea, i will attach to it tomorrow at 8:59AM UTC.

Comment: @djdomi there are no crontab jobs, i already checked, unless it's a fake new crontab inside systemd that i'm not aware of (how to check?)

Comment: @roaima on Linux, testing your own test with sleep, such strace always displays the signal, as well as the sender, its uid, just as what the recipient process could known using the signal handler installed by sigaction(2). Example displayed by strace: `--- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=5745, si_uid=1000} ---` 5745 is the sender (not the recipient).

Comment: @A.B I missed that completely! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [eBPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBPF):

```
sudo dnf install bcc-tools
sudo /usr/share/bcc/tools/killsnoop
```

Here is how it looks when sending `SIGHUP` (-1) from process with `PID` 1221229, which is the `bash` shell where I run the `kill -1 1221227` to process with `PID` 1221227.

```
[mvutcovi@laptop-rh-old ~]$ sudo /usr/share/bcc/tools/killsnoop
TIME      PID    COMM             SIG  TPID   RESULT
01:38:35  1221229 bash             1    1221227 0
^C[mvutcovi@laptop-rh-old ~]$
```

Another way, this time with [ftrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ftrace):

```
sudo dnf install trace-cmd
sudo trace-cmd record -e signal
sudo trace-cmd report
```

Here I am sending SIGHUP to a `sleep` process from a `bash` shell:

```
[mvutcovi@laptop-rh-old ~]$ sudo trace-cmd record -e signal
[mvutcovi@laptop-rh-old ~]$ sudo trace-cmd report
version = 7
cpus=8
           sleep-1221703 [001] 1248579.487042: signal_deliver:       sig=9 errno=0 code=0 sa_handler=0 sa_flags=0
           sleep-1221703 [001] 1248579.487362: signal_generate:      sig=17 errno=0 code=2 comm=bash pid=1221675 grp=1 res=0
[mvutcovi@laptop-rh-old ~]$ sudo rm trace.dat
```